# Troca de mensagens entre objetos, o que significa?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, terminologia

O que significa o termo troca de mensagens entre objetos em Programação Orientada a Objetos?

Comment: A troca de mensagens ocorre através da chamada aos métodos de um objeto por outro objeto.

Comment: Olá, amigo, boa noite! Esses links também poderão te ajudar: [Como exatamente os objetos se comunicam transmitindo mensagens?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347973/how-exactly-do-objects-communicate-with-each-other-by-passing-messages) [Passagem de mensagem entre objetos - Como se referir ao objeto de destino?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/99684/message-passing-between-objects-how-to-refer-to-the-target-object) [O que há de tão especial sobre a passagem de mensagens no smalltalk
](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42498438/whats-so-special-about-message-passing-in-smalltalk) Ab

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Para o uso *mainstream* é o que todo mundo conhece como invocação ou chamada de método. Ou seja, você chama um método e indica que objeto a que está se referindo.

[Smalltalk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smalltalk) é que a linguagem que originou o termo o usa de forma mais correta e tem um significado mais importante e tem um sistema mais sofisticado de invocação, delegação e solução de método inexistente. Ou seja, o objeto tem uma infraestrutura para resolver o que de fato executar. A flexibilidade é enorme, mas a performance costuma ser pobre.

Smalltalk é uma linguagem onde verdadeiramente (não só marketing) tudo é um objeto, inclusive a mensagem e as próprias classes. Isto exige um grande dinamismo na linguagem.

A passagem de mensagem costuma ocorrer por cópia completa do dado que é ótimo para concorrência, mas péssimo para economia de recursos, por isto é algo pouco adotado.

Acertadamente, o termo é pouco utilizado na prática em linguagens como Java, C# ou C++ que possuem um mecanismo mais simples e quase todo resolvido na compilação. Mas existem pessoas que adotam o termo mesmo não sendo exatamente o que ocorre nessas linguagens.

[Artigo na Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_passing).

Leia mais sobre [como o termo acabou associado à OOP sem ser](https://userpage.fu-berlin.de/%7Eram/pub/pub_jf47ht81Ht/doc_kay_oop_en). [Também](https://www.hillelwayne.com/post/alan-kay/). [Complemente com mais isso](https://ovid.github.io/articles/alan-kay-and-oo-programming.html). Uma [discussão mais abrangente pode ser vista no SE.SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/142327/389).

[Para entender melhor toda questão](https://wiki.c2.com/?AlanKaysDefinitionOfObjectOriented). E [OOP não é o que as pessoas aprendem](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/the-forgotten-history-of-oop-88d71b9b2d9f).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Para ficar um pouco mais claro, vc poderia me fornecer um exemplo, em java, de troca de mensagens entre objetos?

Comment: Basicamente não. Porque no fundo Java não tem esta troca. A não ser que você esteja achando que isto é uma troca de mensagem: `objeto1.metodo(objeto2)`. Na verdade isto não pode ser considerado uma troca de mensagem como foi definido em OOP. Mas se quiser usar o termo de qualquer jeito então é só uma chamada simples. Eu sei que muitas pessoas usam o termo para isto, mas ele não se refere ao mecanismo como ele foi definido. Você preguntou sobre o termo e eu tenho que dizer o que ele é. Há muito confusão sobre o que é OOP e o que usamos nessas linguagens não é bem OOP.

Comment: Entendi, essa questão me surgiu porque ouvi muito esse termo como sendo relacionado a OOP, mas não conseguia associar isso com implementação, e uma linguagem que estou aprendendo agora é o Java, por isso pensei que Java utilizava esse conceito

Comment: Não propriamente, até porque Java não é uma linguagem verdadeiramente orientada a objeto na definição formal do paradigma. Claro, ela usa uma forma de OOP, mas é um pouco diferente e uma das principais diferenças é esta mesmo. A passagem de mensagem entre objetos não é um mecanismo sofisticado e dinâmico e sim uma simples chamada de uma função resolvida total ou parcialmente em tempo de compilação.

Comment: Mas se Java não é uma linguagem verdadeiramente orientada a objeto, qual ou quais são?

Comment: Eu escrevi na resposta.

Comment: @bigown E o polimorfismo, o fato de uma chamada polimórfica ter o alvo definido em tempo de execução, não conta como troca de mensagens?

Comment: Contar conta, mas não como é definido formalmente. Não o polimorfismo em si, mas a chamada é que gera a troca. O polimorfismo dá um pequeno toque dinâmico mas é um mecanismo muito simples e limitado. Ruby é uma linguagem que chega bem mais próximo do sistema original de troca de mensagens. Mas engana bem também. E se este mecanismo fosse tão bom seria amplamente usado. O que é e o que não entra em um campo complicado. O que é formal pode ser ignorado e o termo ser usado com sucesso de outra forma que atende bem outros interesses.

Comment: Comentário bem legal @Maniero, complementando, um modelo mais similar ao do Smalltalk utilizado atualmente é o modelo de atores do Elixir. Ele trabalha com objetivos vivos em memória e faz a passagem de mensagens entre eles, inclusive criando filas de mensagens na entrada destes objetos.