# Quais são as escolas de orientação a objeto existentes?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, terminologia, engenharia-de-software

Já vi muito se [falar em escolas de OOP diferentes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=escolas%20oop). Tem algo que estabeleça isso de forma oficial?

O termo "escola" não é tão difundido, mas parece ser [fato notório que elas existem](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/312296/389), que há definições diferentes para o que seria OOP. A questão aqui é sobre essas diferenças, independente do termo. Não é sobre ser escola ou não, mas sobre ter definições diferentes.

Então no que elas diferem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Até onde eu sei, não há nada oficial. Apenas é o que observamos. E a minha observação é que existem escolas bem variadas, nem dá para listar todas porque elas não são tão delimitadas assim. Há crenças de que o certo é uma coisa ou outra. Alguns pontos se destacam mais que outros.

Para não dizer que não tem nada oficial tem a ISO/IEC 2382:2015, item 2122503 (o *link* não funciona mais), mas é só sobre um ou outro termo genérico, nada que se aprofunde. [Veja mensagem do Alan Kay](http://userpage.fu-berlin.de/%7Eram/pub/pub_jf47ht81Ht/doc_kay_oop_en).

A diferença principal é sobre a definição dada pelo Alan Kay, principalmente na criação de Smalltalk e o que as pessoas mais usam em quase todas as tecnologias atuais e que foi popularizada pelo Bjarne Stroustrup através do C++, ainda que o grosso do que foi difundido veio de Simula de Ole-Johan Dahl e Kristen Nygaard.

Antes de desenvolver isso, quero dizer que tem diversas outras formas de pensar sobre essas escolas, e alguns usam certas frases para definir o que é ou não OOP. Por exemplo alguns falam de reuso, ou falam que ela serve para reproduzir o mundo real no código, alguns dizem que o importante é encapsular, há quem diga que basta o objeto estar no foco principal (ele chama métodos em vez de funções usarem ele), e tem quem coloca várias regras para determinar o que é ou não OO. Até mesmo há quem diga que *design* orientado a objeto é diferente de programação orientada a objeto.

Quase tudo isso está certo em certa medida, mas está errado quando olha os detalhes.

Não existe uma fonte canônica sobre isso. Eu já procurei, até achei alguma fonte muito simplista que não ajuda muito. Tem que ir na crença. Você escolhe o que faz mais sentido para você e quando for se comunicar com outros programadores precisa <strike>brigar</strike>informar como é o seu jeito de pensar.

Mais que isso, fazer um *design* bem-feito, com orientação a objeto ou não, é difícil e é isso que importa. Alguns dizem que OO ajuda e outros dizem que ele até pode ajudar, mas se não fizer certo ele atrapalha.

Entenda que orientação a objeto existe para gerenciar complexidade. Tem outras maneiras de obter esse resultado, mas OOP se tornou bastante popular.

## Duas escolas principais

Não a dúvidas que o Alan Kay criou o termo **orientado a objeto**. Ele clama por isso, e é claro que ele deu uma definição do que isso quer dizer.

Porém mais recentemente ele acabou admitindo que o que [ele criou é a orientação a mensagens](http://mythz.servicestack.net/blog/2013/02/27/the-deep-insights-of-alan-kay/). Ele nunca deu muita ênfase nisso, mas disse. Portanto todo mundo que segue o que ele criou e usou o termo orientação a objeto, estava errado, ainda que ele não admitiu que fosse um erro. Mas isso importa pouco, porque o mercado já havia definido outro rumo para o uso da orientação a objeto. Você vai encontrar pessoas defendendo o que ele pregava, mas na prática poucos conseguem aplicar, porque as tecnologias que são usadas foram desenvolvidas de outras formas.

É tão doido, que ele mesmo admite que Lisp, uma linguagem claramente funcional, é mais orientada a objeto que Smalltalk. Curiosamente existe CLOS que é Lisp orientada a objeto. Mas como pode uma linguagem que é mais orientada a objeto que a linguagem que definiu o termo precisar de uma variantes para ser OO? Porque só assim ela passa se conformar com a definição que o mercado mais usa.

Acabou que a definição do Alan Kay virou mais acadêmica. Curiosamente mais imprecisa, porque não foi consagrada e foi revisada.

A escola mais adotada, mas muitas vezes não de forma correta porque mistura pontos da escola do Alan Kay, e até outros pontos vistos em alguns autores que não estão presentes nas definições originais, e isto é um enorme problema, porque são pequenas escolas que vão se criando, e ninguém sabe nada mais, é a escola que C++ consagrou.

Elas não são tão distantes quanto parece, mas criam mecanismos concretos bem diferentes. E proporcionam *designs* muito diferentes nas aplicações.

Não há dúvida que esta escola é vencedora no uso, mas não por completo, porque apesar da ideia básica ser o que ela impõe, algumas ideias originais do Alan Kay são adotadas também. Em linguagens de *script* que são muito populares, os mecanismos de cada uma das escolas estão presentes, dando uma certa liberdade, mas impondo alguma restrição.

Em códigos mais complexos, muitas vezes que exigem mais eficiência, busca-se mais a escola de Simula/C++ de forma mais "pura".

A forma pura criada por Smalltalk, ou mesmo Lisp, é um fracasso completo, não se discute isso. E não estou colocando se deveria, só estou notando o fato.

Vamos a algumas diferenças.

#### Tudo deve ser objeto

Ou seja, tudo é dado. Tudo pode ser manipulado em tempo de execução. Até mesmo o código deve ser assim. Ou seja, mesmo não falando de forma direta a linguagem precisa ser [homoicônica](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/575855/101), pelo menos parcialmente.

Por isso Lisp atende melhor que Smalltalk, que é homoicônica, mas não totalmente.

Até mesmo uma estrutura de decisão deve ser feita através de um objeto usando alguma técnica.

O objeto pode se transformar livremente, como ocorre no mundo real, os objetos não são estáticos. Lembre-se que o Alan Kay era um biólogo, ele precisava pensar em algo que atendesse algumas necessidades dessa área.

Aí é onde começa complicar.

Programar em objetos tão dinâmicos pode sim facilitar a reprodução do mundo, porém vai complicar imensamente a programação, o oposto do que deveria ser o objetivo. Imagine que toda vez que vai usar um objeto você não sabe exatamente como ele se compõe ou até mesmo como se comporta. Precisa verificar a capacidade dele fazer algo o tempo todo, ou testar de forma insana para que percorra todas as possibilidades do que pode acontecer com o objeto e em todas não dê problema; ou rezar.

Isso não é uma evolução.

E ainda não comecei falar do quanto isso é ineficiente, algo que na época era um enorme problema, mas que acreditava-se que o tempo resolveria e nunca precisaríamos pensar nisso. Mas o tempo provou o contrário.

Algumas tecnologias adotaram essa característica de que o objeto é dinâmico. Em geral são linguagens mais dinâmicas, com tipagem dinâmica. Poucas resolverem ser homoicônicas. E as que são, tem baixíssima popularidade.

Mesmo com objetos bem dinâmicos muitas vezes há restrições do quanto pode manipular um objeto, e na prática o que pode mudar raramente é feito em códigos reais, de aplicações complexas. As pessoas que estudam o assunto sabem que isso é inviável, e as outras que só seguem "boas práticas" imitam isso.

Curiosamente essa é uma boa prática não muito escrita. As melhores boas práticas são aquelas que acontecem sem ninguém dizer nada. Quantas vezes você já viu alguém dizendo para não ficar deformando os objetos? Todo mundo sabe que não deve fazer isso, intuitivamente. Ou pelo menos porque "ninguém" ensina fazer.

O Bjarne adotou em C++, quase na mesma época do Smalltalk, e popularizou porque quase todas as outras linguagens que vieram depois adotaram um pouco essa forma, de linguagem mais estática em alguns ou todos os sentidos, mas principalmente que o objeto não se transforma, depois dele criado passa ser um contrato que o compilador pode ajudar. Aqui começa a cisão que fez o Alan dizer que isso que ele vê por aí não é orientação a objeto.

Não vou entrar muito na questão aqui, mas tem estudos que mostram que no longo prazo a dinamicidade pode tornar a produtividade mais baixa. Mas ela pode ajudar entregar um resultado rápido. E quem acha diferente provavelmente deve achar que não fazer testes também é algo bom, porque é a mesma coisa. Em linguagem dinâmica você tem muito mais código para lidar ou menos robustez, tem que escolher.

#### Tipagem estática X dinâmica

Tudo isso sobre dinamicidade acaba refletindo no [estilo de tipagem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/190463/101). Optar por um ou outro quase obriga um estilo de tipagem mais dinâmico ou mais estático. Ou até mais nominal ou mais estrutural.

Em algum momento é possível cruzar a linha de um lado para ou outro, mas isso não costuma fazer muito sentido e fica confuso. Um pode contaminar o outro. As linguagens que querem entregar as duas coisas são estranhas e, embora tenham alguns benefícios de ambas, pegam os malefícios de ambas. Tudo é uma questão do quanto consegue isolar isso do resto do código. Por isso linguagens mais estáticas que flexibilizam em alguns pontos costumam ter mais benefícios que malefícios, comparando com as que são mais dinâmicas e querem ser mais rígidas em alguns pontos e não conseguem muito benefícios, trazendo os mesmos malefícios do outro lado.

#### Classes x protótipos

Já vi lugares dizendo que o Alan Kay nunca falou sobre classes, mas já vi lugares definindo que ele falou sobre isso, desde que a classe possa ser alterada, e que ela seja um objeto.

Então eu entendo que ele nunca falou de classes estáticas, ele falou de classes que na verdade são protótipos, entretanto parece que usou o termo.

Você pode chamar do que quiser, mas os termos acabaram se rivalizando onde a classe é uma definição que não é um objeto, é só um modelo de como um objeto deve ser criado, e não pode ser modificada, e o protótipo já é um objeto que é um modelo a ser copiado para outro objeto e pode ser modificado.

Ambos são uma forma de modularização e isso é importante. Existem outras formas de modularizar que não são através de classes e objetos protótipos, que não vem ao caso aqui. Só temos a certeza que modularizar é muito importante. Junto com a linguagem de alto nível e o gerenciamento automático de memória foram as grandes balas de prata da computação que permitiram escalar o desenvolvimento de software.

É mais fácil lidar com complexidade com um mapeamento mais estável. É mais fácil pensar em hierarquias em classes do que em protótipos. E nenhum problema em usar protótipos, mas é mais fácil perder o controle neles, justamente pela flexibilidade. Mais flexível é mais difícil de gerenciar.

De uma certa forma, mudar o objeto de forma tão livre é permitir o código se modificar, o que é poderoso, não tem dúvida, mas é capaz de criar muitas situações inesperadas. É o pesadelo do programador.

A primeira forma prega o uso de estruturas de dados estáticas e membros bem definidos, enquanto a segunda forma prega uma lista mutável de membros de dados e comportamentos livres.

Na prática o programador se freia em usar muito a segunda forma, conforme vai ficando mais claro ao longo deste texto.

E não se engane, as linguagens de *scripts* mais conhecidas trabalham com protótipos, mesmo que exista uma sintaxe que permite criar os objetos como se fossem classes. Porém de forma um pouco restrita.

Programação mais flexível exige muito mais ferramenta, mais disciplina, mais testes, mais planejamento e até mais código.

Uma escola optou pelo poder e flexibilidade e a outra optou pela facilidade de gerenciar o código. Uma foi para o lado que atendia mais as necessidades da biologia e outra mais ao trabalho do programador. Uma facilitou escrever e funcionar, outra privilegiou o contrato estar certo.

#### Interfaces X classes

Além disso a escola mais poderosa e flexível, a do Alan Kay e outros, prefere mais que as classes ou protótipos sejam apenas *containers* de estado e comportamento, enquanto que o que o Bjarne Stroustrup popularizou, preza mais pelo contrato. Até mesmo tendo classes que funcionam de forma implícita ou explícita como interfaces ou protocolos para o que o objeto deve executar.

Aqui não estou falando das diferenças específicas de semântica nas linguagens quando há sintaxe específica com esses nomes. Por isso não vou *linkar* onde fala sobre o que é cada uma, não faz sentido aqui.

Interfaces fornecem contratos, classes (protótipos) fornecem implementações. Pode ser que encontre ambos na mesma construção da linguagem. Algumas linguagens só conseguem expressar interfaces através de classes.

#### *Late* X *early binding*

[Já escrevi em específico sobre o assunto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/577332/101). Também tem a ver com flexibilidade ou contrato, pelo menos em parte. O primeiro é mais poderoso e flexível, porém menos robusto, já o segundo é mais eficiente e robusto, por isso mais fácil de usar e de ter melhor resultado computacional.

Protótipos são inerentemente *late biding*, ainda que possa colocar algum limite artificial, tirando a flexibilidade, e de certa forma transformando em classe. Geralmente usam algo chamado [*duck typing*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/574146/101) cujo contrato é "basta funcionar".

Em alguns casos permite-se [despacho múltiplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/448123/101) para dar total flexibilidade que o objeto pode precisar, e isso é bem complicado de implementar em uma linguagem, e de usar.

#### Polimorfismo hierárquico ou por passagem de mensagens

Com hierarquias bem definidas é possível fazer o polimorfismo de forma mais estática ou dinâmica. A última geralmente feita com um mecanismo do tipo [*vtable*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/577815/101). Então há uma clareza do que pode modelar um objeto e foi o que o Stroustrup optou. E é o que quase todo mundo estuda. Algo que facilita o ser humano ter controle de como funciona.

Quando essas hierarquias não são bem definidas você só pode contar com o que o Kay definiu como [passagem de mensagens](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/86479/101), que espera que o objeto saiba como lidar. Aqui você diz o que quer e torce para o objeto conseguir dar o resultado esperado ou lidar com o fato de não conseguir, talvez delegando para acontecer outra coisa em outro objeto. Ótimo para biologia, mas estruturas vivas são menos gerenciáveis.

Indo ao extremo, o próprio código pode ser criado no momento da execução quando lida só com mensagens passadas. Na prática existem funções prontas em algum ponto do código que são vinculadas com os protótipos. Em tese pode mudar isso em todos os objetos em qualquer momento com total liberdade.

#### Herança simples X múltipla

Mesmo C++ adotou um estilo mais flexível e poderoso de herança múltipla, algo normal em protótipos ou objetos tão flexíveis que permitem qualquer coisa que queira ser montada, desde que funcione e entregue o resultado.

Com o tempo, descendentes de C++ optaram por uma rigidez maior com o aprendizado da dificuldade de implementar isso nas linguagens, e o fardo que impunha ao programador que tenta fazer hierarquias tão complexas.

Então o tempo foi criando uma sub-escola mais rígida ainda, e mais um braço de como OOP pode ser. Com regras mais simples fica muito mais fácil manipular os objetos.

O uso de [interfaces](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/107524/101), [traits](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/156913/101), [mixings](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/42970/101) e até [métodos de extensão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/136913/101), entre outros mecanismos, foram sendo adotados para dar mais contrato e permitir a junção de comportamentos e até estado, vindos de fontes diferentes no mesmo objeto, mas com muito mais controle.

A definição original do Alan Kay não fala em herança porque a flexibilidade deve ser até maior que isso. O mecanismo de herança é até mais restritivo.

Não precisa nem dizer qual funciona melhor para biologia ou engenharia, já entendeu, né?

#### *Information hiding* e encapsulamento

Esses dois assuntos são muito mal compreendidos e eu mesmo não sei se ainda estou com a definição certa. Todo mundo que aprende de um jeito tende a vender o que aprendeu como o jeito certo, mesmo que não seja.

Não há dúvida que ambos sempre foram objetivos do Alan Kay, até mesmo a ideia da passagem de mensagens indica isso indiretamente.

O primeiro tem a ver com fazer com que o estado não seja visível para fora do objeto, e apenas métodos possam manipular o estado. E daí nascem as escolas que dizem que: a) basta ter um método que cria uma abstração; b) o método deve fazer uma ação mais abstrata, que por acaso pode mudar o estado.

É muito comum as pessoas dizerem que isso aí é o [encapsulamento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/240186/101), mas é só *information hiding*. Então cria-se até escolas informais erradas.

O encapsulamento é algo interessante e parece estar presente em OO desde o início em qualquer escola. Ele indica tratar o objeto como uma cápsula, algo único que tem uma casca segurando o conteúdo de dentro. Daí talvez faça sentido a confusão. Mas meu entendimento, hoje, é que a cápsula serve para tornar tudo como uma coisa só e criar uma coesão, algo necessário na biologia, engenharia e outras áreas.

Não digo que sejam duas escolas, mas dois entendimentos diferentes.

Há quem discorde.

#### Abstração

Esse assunto é mais complicado porque é óbvio que o objeto tem como função criar uma abstração de mecanismos diversos necessários para que ele funcione adequadamente. Mas não é fácil achar uma boa definição do que se fala em específico sobre abstração em programação orientada a objeto.

Algumas pessoas definem a abstração como o encapsulamento. Há até quem fale sobre a herança, ou seja, o tipo base é uma abstração (generalização) do tipo derivado. E até, equivocamente, falam do fato de existir um mecanismo em algumas linguagens que tornam um tipo como forçadamente geral, abstrato, e não concreto.

Gerenciar complexidade tem a ver com criar abstrações.

Mais um caso que não encontra escolas diferentes, mas algumas pessoas colocam isso como importante ou não.

#### Sobrecarga de operador

Já vi isto como um item que define como pilar de OOP. Ou seja, ser capaz de estabelecer um comportamento para um operador em cada tip ode de objeto. Alguns dirão que é só uma forma mais específica de passagem de mensagem para o operador.

Eu não gosto dessa necessidade, mas há autores que usam como requisito. [Mesmo a forma mais restritiva não costuma falar nisso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/215679/101).

Muitas pessoas ignoram completamente. E se ele for válido, muitas linguagens não seriam orientadas a objeto por não atender isso.

#### Pureza

Algumas linguagens podem se vender como puramente orientadas a objeto. Para isso ser fato, precisam ser homoicônicas, como já citado antes. Até Smalltalk tem dificuldade de atender completamente isto. Todas as mais comuns, imperativas, que de fato as pessoas usam, não são puras, nem tudo é objeto. Mesmo as que excluem o código na definição, mas o resto (dados) seria uma forma de objeto, podem falhar isso. Não é simples alcançar a pureza, e o mérito disso é questionável, talvez não, se está trabalhando com biologia e afins.

Algumas linguagens são tão pouco puras que nem mesmo todos os objetos são considerados objetos no sentido de existir um objeto que rege todos os demais. Independente disto, para tratar tudo de maneira uniforme traz ineficiência e por isso as linguagens tendem a não seguir isso tão estritamente, em alguns casos criam a ilusão de ser tudo como objeto, como faz C#. Ou abrem mão de forma direta de tudo ser derivado de objeto, como faz Java, e mais ainda C++ que nada é derivado do mesmo objeto universal.

Algumas pessoas querem até trazer o [monopólio de criar objeto apenas quando usa OOP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/205482/101), o que é um completo *non-sense*.

Em função das pessoas não entenderem muito do assunto, fez-se muito marketing em torno de pureza de linguagens que não chegam nem perto de serem OO puras.

#### Mutabilidade

Isso não é muito comum de falar porque a mutabilidade dos objetos é o padrão em quase tudo que se vê na prática na área. Mas nada impede ter uma escola que escolha o objeto ser mais imutável. E algumas tecnologias já permitem escolher isso pelo menos em alguns contextos.

Nota-se que procura-se fugir cada vez mais da pureza, da flexibilidade, da escola que alguns dizem ser a original, a que definou o termo.

Mas aqui até mesmo a escola mais rígida ainda não consegue aceitar bem. Começa ter outro tipo de ineficiência que era tudo o que não se buscava quando foi adotada em C++, a "linguagem da eficiência".

#### Mais uma definição

[Já vi até mesmo alguém dizendo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/88546/101) que basta o sujeito (objeto) vir na frente do adjetivo (estado ou comportamento) e já diz que é orientado a objeto. E de forma simples faz algum sentido.

## Consolidação das duas definições e outras:

Alan Kay diz:

> - Tudo é um objeto.
> - Os objetos se comunicam enviando e recebendo mensagens (em termos de objetos).
> - Os objetos têm sua própria memória (em termos de objetos).
> - Todo objeto é uma instância de uma classe (que deve ser um objeto).
> - A classe mantém o comportamento compartilhado por suas instâncias (na forma de objetos em uma lista de programas).
> - Para avaliar uma lista de programas, o controle é passado para o primeiro objeto e o restante é tratado como sua mensagem.

-- [Fonte](http://worrydream.com/EarlyHistoryOfSmalltalk/).

E o Bjarne Stroustrup diz:

> Dados esses critérios gerais para uma definição de "orientados a
> objetos", você pode encontrar vários candidatos plausíveis, e várias
> comunidades têm suas próprias definições. No entanto, sugiro que
> mantemos a definição tradicional de orientação de objetos usada em
> amplas comunidades de programadores. Uma linguagem ou técnica é
> orientada a objetos se e somente se ele apoiar diretamente:
>
> - Abstração - fornecendo alguma forma de classes e objetos.
> - Herança - fornecendo a capacidade de criar novas abstrações fora das existentes.
> - Polimorfismo em tempo de execução fornecendo alguma forma de ligação em tempo de execução.

-- [Fonte](https://www.stroustrup.com/whatis.pdf).

[image: Alan Kay dizendo o que é para ele][image: Bjarne Stroustrup dizendo o que é para ele]

Sabe o que é mais incrível? O primeiro acha que [sua criação, Smalltalk não é tão orientada a objeto assim](https://www.quora.com/What-did-Alan-Kay-mean-by-I-made-up-the-term-object-oriented-and-I-can-tell-you-I-did-not-have-C++-in-mind). Acha até Lisp e outras linguagens mais. O segundo [diz que C++, sua criação, não é OO nem por seus próprios critérios](https://www.stroustrup.com/oopsla.pdf).

> A execução de um programa é considerada como um modelo físico, simulando o comportamento de uma parte real ou imaginária do mundo.

-- Kristen Nygaard

Esta é uma frase do criador da OO que usamos hoje amplamente. Já vi argumento dos "puristas" da OO que isso nunca foi dito sobre OO, o que claramente não é verdade. As pessoas fazem *cherry picking* para decidir o que é OOP. Não estou aqui chancelando que isto seja certo, pelo contrário, eu acho isso tão inviável quanto a definição do Alan Kay.

Já vi quem diz que o termo foi sequestrado, e no fundo só importa fazer a programação procedural mais modularizada e com mecanismos melhores, que é o que todo mundo faz, e deram esse nome, mesmo sem ele fazer sentido, então a técnica seria boa, o termo não. Não vou citar o autor porque não é alguém relevante nisso.

O Uncle Bob, que muitas pessoas adoram, é contra o que o Alan Kay prega, e afirma que ele está errado. Faça seu julgamento.

E ele prega muito o SOLID e o reuso, mesmo que alguns digam que não tem nada a ver, entre outros princípios, como parte importante de orientação a objeto e que caberia até em sua definição, pelo menos no *design*, o que poderia abrir uma frente diferente dos mecanismos de OO, que falam nos tais 3 ou 4 pilares famosos.

Já vi quem diga que OO é só uma extensão da definição de tipos pelos usuários, ou seja é uma `struct` mais sofisticada. E está errado? Talvez sim, por reforçar o "só". Mas é outra forma de ver tudo isso.

Todo mundo ignora essas coisas. Porque basta repetir o que está em maior número na internet, ou em menor número, mas seja o que ela acredita.

## Conclusão

Por causa dessas duas ou mais escolas, ninguém sabe o que é OOP, estudam fragmentos do que isso quer dizer, e ninguém se entende. Como cada um usa uma combinação diferente, em alguns casos consagrada por algum autor, não existe OOP, existem formas de OOP.

A única regra que importa é o que faz o código ficar melhor, o que torna ele mais fácil de dar manutenção, o que é mais produtivo trabalhar com ele, o que fica mais óbvio aos olhos dos humanos, e o que ferramentas podem ajudar.

Regras de "isso pode ou não pode" só devem ser usadas para atender esses objetivos, não para agradar o santo A ou B. Não importa que escola usa, se mistura coisas, importa o software ficar melhor. Em muitos casos é não adotar a escola da orientação a objeto.

Sem saber exatamente o que é, pode atrapalhar usar corretamente. Você pode até escolher uma escola, mas precisa fazer certo. Precisa saber por que está fazendo aquilo, o que espera ganhar e ver se está ganhando.

Infelizmente temos algo extremamente popular que precisa ser definido em muitos detalhes em uma conversa profissional antes da conversa poder ser produtiva. Esse é o estado na nossa área, e quanto ela vai se afastando do que é ciência.

O fato das pessoas não saberem disso é a parte pior.

O objetivo aqui é eu começar consolidar alguns conhecimentos sobre o assunto para quem sabe fazer algo maior depois, em outro local, quem sabe um livro, blog ou vídeo. Sei que é um pouco tarde, o erro já foi repetido tantas vezes para tanta gente que não adianta muito mais tentar consertar. Não é uma tese, mas é um início.

Também é objeto receber *feedback*. Não tem verdade absoluta aqui. Dá para melhorar.

[Vale a leitura](https://www.sigcis.org/files/Hsu%20--%20Software%20Crisis%20and%20OOP.pdf).

[C2 wiki como fonte](https://wiki.c2.com/?NobodyAgreesOnWhatOoIs). C2 wiki é sensacional, e usei diversas páginas para construir esta resposta. Chegou uma hora que achei que tinha que parar, porque puxava um fio e vinha um novelo inteiro. Ach oque aqui já deu uma base sobre a resposta.

A conclusão final é que **ninguém sabe o que é orientação a objeto**.